# Angular service function being called multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular service function that is being called multiple times.
In the `index.html` page I have the following line:

```
<li><i class="pull-right"></i><br/>{{appCtrl.service.getCurrentUser()}}&nbsp;</li>
```

In the application controller I set the variable

```
appCtrl.controller('AppController', function ($state, securityService, $log) {

        $log.info('App controller');

        var appCtrl = this;
        appCtrl.service = securityService;
});
```

In my service I exposed the function

```
   login.factory('securityService', function ($window, $log) {

    var currentUser;

    return {
        setCurrentUser: function (user) {
            currentUser = user;
            $window.sessionStorage.setItem('User', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
        },
        getCurrentUser: function () {
            $log.info('Calling current user');
            if (!currentUser) {
                var storedObject = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('User');
                currentUser = JSON.parse(storedObject);
            }
            return currentUser;
        }
    }
});
```

The following line in the `getCurrentUser` function gets called multiple times when the application starts up or page refresh is being done.

```
$log.info('Calling current user');
```

The controller is being called only once, I monitor it by looking at `$log.info('App controller');`

Is it being called as part of the dirty checking process or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Angular calls your function on every **digest** cycle, you can set breakpoint inside the function and check it. If you are on 1.3 version, then please take a look at [One Time Binding](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html) feature. If not then call the service inside the controller and bind view to some scope variable:

```
$scope.currentUser = securityService.getCurrentUser();
```

And inside view bind to scope variable:

```
{{currentUser}}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem with setting the function to a variable on the app controller is that the app controller sets the variable to the initial value with app startup (which is undefined). When the `setCurrentUser` on the factory gets called from the login controller the variable in the app controller doesn't get updated.

Comment: Then I would use some standard event mechanism (all this $broadcast/$emit/$on stuff) to update other controllers when user value updated by login controller.

Comment: Thank you udalmik, I have gone for the $broadcast and $on strategy. It works perfectly for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is correct factory declaration. Because internally AngularJS calls yout factory like: `securityService(injects);` , each time you inject (use) your factory.

```
login.factory('securityService', function ($window, $log) {
        var currentUser;
        return {

            setCurrentUser: function (user) {
                currentUser = user;
                $window.sessionStorage.setItem('User', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
            },
            getCurrentUser: function () {
                $log.info('Calling current user');
                if (!currentUser) {
                    var storedObject = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('User');
                    currentUser = JSON.parse(storedObject);
                }
                return currentUser;
            }  
        };

});
```